Violent movie from <= 1980
I'm trying to find a movie that I watched on cable (HBO, in the US) in 1980 or 81 when I was a kid. It was a thriller, very violent with a fair bit of nudity and a couple of very violent scenes:

A couple have sex in a small room with little furniture and vertically striped wallpaper. It was like a doctor's exam room or similar. After sex, the man beats the woman to death by crushing her skull. 
The same man (I think) beats another woman at a big open apartment. In the struggle an aquarium is broken and he decapitates her on a big triangle of jagged glass sticking up from the aquarium. He wraps her body in a rug and carries her out. 

I was only 12 when I saw this, and those are the only 2 scenes that I remember. It was in color and in English. 
I don't remember what the man looked like or much else

Definitely The Silent Partner, (1978), with Christopher Plummer inflicting the violence.  There isn't much about it in the plot summary other than this:

A few days later, Reikle is released from jail and confronts Elaine
  one night over where her loyalties lie. When Elaine admits that she
  has indeed fallen in love with Miles, an enraged Reikle murders and
  decapitates her at Miles' apartment. Miles is forced to dispose of her
  body in the foundation for the new bank building to avoid being
  investigated by the police.


Yes! That's it! Thank you so much for relieving the itch that's been in my brain for the last (gulp!) 34 years!
